# JSTL - How to parse input date

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I have a date input field in my jsp like this:

`<form:input name="inputDate" id="inputDate" value="" path="date"/>`

This form is mapped to a `@ModelAttribute` `account` which has the date defined like this:

`private java.util.Date date ;`

When I submit the form, I get an error (of course) that says:

> Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required
>   type java.util.Date ...

Please suggest a way I can parse `date` in the JSP itself, so that the `@ModelAttribute` can directly set the `date` field with the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just [register binder in your `@Controller`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-initbinder) like in this example:

```
@Controller
public class MyFormController {

  @InitBinder
  public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class,
        new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, false));
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: That sure helped, @xaerxess. Thanks

Comment: Can you please help me a little further? The binding is working fine for me, but when there's an unparsable date in the input field, it throws this exception: `Could not parse date: Unparseable date: <my_date>` This is directly fed into the `BindingResult`, so it appears in the jsp. I dont want the user to see this error. How can I issue a custom error?

Comment: Then what do you want to do if user enters invalid date string?

Comment: I want to show a more comprehensible error. say, "You entered an Invalid date" rather than some java exception.

Comment: Just add `typeMismatch.java.util.Date = You entered an invalid date (date format should be yyyy-mm-dd)` to your messages.

Comment: btw, It turns out that the error code is just `typeMismatch`. Now the problem is, even if I reset the error message by doing `result.rejectValue("date", "typeMismatch", "new message") ;`, it shows both the old and the new messages. Is there any way I can remove a `FieldError` from a `BindingResult`?

Comment: Hmm... It's completely different problem than original question, I think you should answer new question and post more details there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Please see my new question posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514587/spring-how-to-remove-a-fielderror-from-a-bindingresult