# Spring - How to remove a `FieldError` from a BindingResult?

Tags: java, spring

I have a `BindingResult result` that has a `FieldError` registered for the field `date`. How can I remove this error?

Assume the error was added as `result.rejectValue("date", "my_code", "my_message") ;`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, first of all, BindingResult is an interface, not a concrete class, and the interface doesn't specify any way to remove an error.

Depending on which implementation of the interface you are dealing with, there may be a method (beyond what's specified in the BindingResult interface) to do this, but it seems unlikely.

The only thing that I can think of is to create a new BindingResult instance, then loop through the errors and re-create all but the one that you want to ignore in the new one.

Comment: Oh, that's so sad. Do you happen to know any such implementation that lets one remove errors? Btw, my declaration goes like this: `org.springframework.validation.BindingResult result`.

Comment: No, I'm not aware of one, probably because this just doesn't come up in 'normal' usage. As John Vint points out in his answer, it might be better to examine why the error is there in the first place.

Comment: I am facing the same problem with one object binding two forms in one single page. It's not really pretty but you can filter the error list like this : `List<ObjectError> allErrors = bindingResult.getAllErrors();` then get the message of the DefaultMessageSourceResolvable and remove the object from the list if necessary.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example that implements @GreyBeardedGuy Answer, Suppose you want to remove the `error` linked to a `field` called `specialField` in the `class` `MyModel` with a `modelAttribute` name as `myModel` from `BindingResult` `result`:

```
List<FieldError> errorsToKeep = result.getFieldErrors().stream()
                .filter(fer -> !fer.getField().equals("specialField "))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        result = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(vacancyDTO, "vacancyDTO");

        for (FieldError fieldError : errorsToKeep) {
            result.addError(fieldError);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The important question is, how did it get there in the first place? I assume `date` is a java.util.Date field and the binding failed because of a formatting issue?

For instance you put in `01/01/1970` and it expected `1970-01-01` or something similar?  The reason here is because Spring MVC has a default date binder.  It needs to take a string representation of a date and turn it into a java.util.Date and failed because it doesnt match the appropriate format.

Take a look at [@InitBinder](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/InitBinder.html) and how to override the [string-to-date](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/beans/propertyeditors/CustomDateEditor.html) conversion to accept different formats.

Comment: Actually, I *am* using `@InitBinder`. The problem is, I dont have control over the errors thrown by Spring. Maybe I dont want to be bothered about all the errors.

Comment: @th3an0maly I guess my point is, if you are using @InitBinder you should have control of whether or not that application is adding via `rejectValue` right?  You should just prevent it yourself from being added.

Comment: I couldn't find anything on deciding when the `@InitBinder` throws an error