# Reset errors on Spring BindingResult

Tags: java, spring, binding

I am trying to use the spring data binding classes to use in my own framework, which is non-spring-mvc based.

In this I override the **DataBinder** and the **AbstractBindingResult** classes. When the user is editing the object, validation can occur, which will run through the binder, which will validate the whole object.

However, once the the user edits one field/value, a whole new result isn't needed, only the specific field/value needs to be revalidated. Luckily, I can extend the default implementations for that.

What I can't seem to do is clean up old errors for that specific field, because the errors list is rendered add-only by the AbstractBindingResult implementation.

So my questions are:

- Is there a way to clean up errors that I am missing?
- Is there a reason why this implementation is chosen?
- Do people have other suggestions how to do this?
- Perhaps pick another validation framework, or just take the AbstractBindingResult code and rewrite
  it?

Comment: So you have found the reason for this elsewere ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, we ended up rewriting our validation framework without the use of spring data binders.

Comment: Here is a related answer to that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12514784/7786270