# How to validate a single field in a Spring bean?

Tags: validation, spring-mvc

It seems like the preferred way to validate a spring annotated bean is by using @valid, like in the block below, however I want to display error messages one field at a time still using Spring annotations. I know I can validate the whole form after each field and show only messages for a single field, but that is inefficient, anyone know of a better way?

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/register",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody RegisterResponse registerSubmit(@Valid @ModelAttribute("registerData") Register registerData, BindingResult result ){

    RegisterResponse rr= new RegisterResponse();
    if(!result.hasErrors()) {
         rr.setStatus("SUCCESS");
         rr.setResult(result);
    }
    else {
         rr.setStatus("FAIL");
         rr.setResult(result.getAllErrors());
    }
    return rr;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return from the `Validator#validate` method upon hitting the first `Error`.

For this

You need to have a Custom `Validator` implementing `org.springframework.validation.Validator` where you have control of validating the fields in the order you need, whereas, using `@Valid` annotation will validate all the fields in your Form Bean and return the `BindingResult` for all the fields.

Comment: Are you suggesting to make a custom validator? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: I cannot seem to find any sample code that does this, I imagine there should be a few lines which trigger annotation validation one at a time? Just to be clear I do not want to have custom validation code, I still want to rely on the annotations, but get the results one at a time.

Comment: @BaradiBaradari AFAIK you cannot intercept the the Validation process while using `@Valid`. All you can do is remove the unwanted `Errors` from `BindingResult` Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514587/spring-how-to-remove-a-fielderror-from-a-bindingresult and Im not sure if that works. Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you Niranjan, I ended up having a working solution albeit not as efficient as I wanted, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make things work by filtering out the errors that had an empty/null fields, this does work but is a bit inefficient since we validate entire bean even though we care for the first field. I'd love to hear of a better way to accomplish this kind of step by step form field validation.
I used something like the following:

```
    private List<ObjectError> removeEmpties(BindingResult result) {
    List<ObjectError> errors = result.getAllErrors();

    ArrayList<ObjectError> myErrors = new ArrayList<ObjectError>();

    for(ObjectError error: errors){

        FieldError realThing = (FieldError) error; 
        if (realThing.getRejectedValue()!=null && !realThing.getRejectedValue().toString().isEmpty()){
            myErrors.add(error);
        }
    }
    return myErrors;
}
```